# Android Mapbox dynamically create a SymbolLayer

Tags: android, mapbox

I'm still getting my head around the various approaches I can take to plotting points! Does a SymbolManager have as much flexibility as the SymbolLayer option? I'm unable to find much in the way of data related styling options with the SymbolManager. I'm currently using a SymbolManager, but only because I can't figure out how to dynamically create a SymbolLayer given a variable list of points! I considered creating a geoJson file on the fly but that seems a bit much? The only options I've been able to find are to load source layers from an asset or url.
EDIT: I'm also struggling to figure out how to clear all the data from a SymbolManager,  or alternatively remove a symbolManager from the map?

Answer (score 2):

`SymbolManager` is getting closer and closer to feature parity with the `SymbolLayer`, but its main advantage is easy of use.

To answer your questions about the manager - for now, it uses only constants for styling, but if you'd like to use `Expression`s, the support is on its way and should be available in the `v0.4.0`. You can remove an annotation by calling `SymbolManager#delete`, and in order to remove them all, simply iterate through the array that can be obtained with `SymbolManager#getAnnotations`.

When it comes to dynamically managing datasets of the `SymbolLayer`, the best approach would be using `FeatureCollection`. You can create `Feature` objects (which are equivalent to GeoJSON features) with static factories like `Feature#fromLngLat` and  `FeatureCollection#fromFeatures`. Then set this collection on your `GeoJsonSource` and you should be ready to go. Check out [the example activity](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/master/platform/android/MapboxGLAndroidSDKTestApp/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/testapp/activity/annotation/AnimatedSymbolLayerActivity.java) that generates features on the fly.